# web3 - get all contract public variables?

Tags: solidity, web3js

I have an abstract worker contract and few that inherit from it. Those contracts have some public variables, each one different. I want to display them on my website. Is there any way to return all getters from contract, or do I need to create a special function getFields() with multiple return for each one?